# Loop or Function in R that for Multiple Analyses with Similar Variables

Tags: r, function, loops, r-lavaan

Relatively new to [r](/questions/tagged/r), and I'm trying to figure out how to run an identical analysis for two different sets of variables. This isn't my data, but here's how my code looks right now:

```
library(lavaan)
names(PoliticalDemocracy)

listoftype <- c("x", "y") 

anexample <- function(tst) {
  model <- '
     tst3 ~ 
          + tst1 
          + tst2
'

  runmodel <- lavaan::sem(model, 
                                        data = PoliticalDemocracy,
                                        missing = "default",
                                        estimator = "ML",
                                        se = "default",
  )
  lavaan::summary(runmodel, fit.measures=FALSE)
  modelsummary <-lavaan::summary(runmodel, fit.measures=FALSE)
  write(paste(utils::capture.output(summary(runmodel)),
              collapse = "\n"), file = paste0("output_",tst.txt))
  tst <-as.data.frame(modelsummary)

}

lapply(listoftype, FUN = anexample)
```

You can probably figure out what I'm trying to do, but the basic idea is that I'm trying to run the first analysis with x3, x2, and x1 and then the second one with y3, y2, and y1. I am trying to insert either "x" or "y" wherever I have "tst". I tried doing it with a loop as well (which is what I would use in other statistical packages) but that didn't work either, and my understanding is that [lapply](/questions/tagged/lapply) would work better for this purpose if I could ever figure it out.

So far, the error message I am getting is:

> lavaan ERROR: missing observed variables in dataset: tst3 tst1 tst2

So clearly, R doesn't recognize that it's supposed to insert "x" or "y" where "tst" is located. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get this to run? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you do not actually substitute `x` or `y` for `tst`. See e.g.

```
library(stringr)

anexample <- function(tst) {
  model <- 'tst3 ~ + tst1 + tst2'
  model <- str_replace_all(model, 'tst', tst)
  return(model)
  }

lapply(listoftype, FUN = anexample)
[[1]]
[1] "x3 ~ + x1 + x2"

[[2]]
[1] "y3 ~ + y1 + y2"
```

So, the following should work:

```
anexample <- function(tst) {
  model <- 'tst3 ~ + tst1 + tst2'
  model <- str_replace_all(model, 'tst', tst)

  runmodel <- lavaan::sem(model, 
                          data = PoliticalDemocracy,
                          missing = "default",
                          estimator = "ML",
                          se = "default",
  )
  lavaan::summary(runmodel, fit.measures=FALSE)
  modelsummary <-lavaan::summary(runmodel, fit.measures=FALSE)
  write(paste(utils::capture.output(summary(runmodel)),
              collapse = "\n"), file = paste0("output_",tst, '.txt'))
  tst <-as.data.frame(modelsummary)

}

lapply(listoftype, FUN = anexample)
```

To get your results with the appropriate name, have a look at the following as an example:

```
anexample <- function(tst) {
  model <- str_replace_all('tst3 ~ + tst1 + tst2', 'tst', tst)
  runmodel <- lavaan::sem(model, 
                          data = PoliticalDemocracy,
                          missing = "default",
                          estimator = "ML",
                          se = "default",
  )
  modelsummary <-lavaan::summary(runmodel, fit.measures=FALSE)
  return(as.data.frame(modelsummary))
}

output <- setNames(lapply(listoftype, anexample), listoftype)
str(output)
List of 2
 $ x:'data.frame':  6 obs. of  8 variables:
  ..$ PE.lhs   : chr [1:6] "x3" "x3" "x3" "x1" ...
  ..$ PE.op    : chr [1:6] "~" "~" "~~" "~~" ...
... 
 $ y:'data.frame':  6 obs. of  8 variables:
  ..$ PE.lhs   : chr [1:6] "y3" "y3" "y3" "y1" ...
  ..$ PE.op    : chr [1:6] "~" "~" "~~" "~~" ...
...
```

This gives you a list with both `x` and `y`. To 'move' this into the global environment, you can additionally use `list2env(output, globalenv())`.

Comment: This is great, fixed a lot of other stuff too. Only remaining issue: I can't generate an object titled "x" or "y" with the last line of the function, even after global assignment (<<-). Do you have advice on how to generate an object that is named after the value of tst?

Comment: You would do that with `assign`, but a more Rtistic way of doing it would be to return `tst` in a named list, or to name the outcome of `lapply` after the run with `setNames`.

Comment: Can't say I'm Rtistic--I'm quite new at this--but I figured out how to do it with assign. Thanks!